# Getting <div align="xx"> functionality in CSS

Tags: html, alignment, text-align

Apparently DIV's `align` attribute has been removed in HTML5, and the advice of course is to "use CSS's `text-align` instead". However, `text-align` doesn't perform the same as the `align` attribute did. Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/5ghoxh1q/

What is correct way in CSS to emulate the behaviour of DIV's `align` attribute?

EDIT: I'm aware of the CSS margin "auto" approach, but that requires the centred element to be fixed width, and also does not work in earlier browsers. I'm after the exact functionality that the `align` attribute approach provides, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish this particular scenario using an auto `margin`. For example:

```
<div>
    <div style="margin: auto; width: 300px; border:1px solid green;">
        This doesn't work the same.
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's an updated [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ghoxh1q/1/).

The `auto` value for `margin` essentially tells the browser to evenly split the margin on the element's box model to center it within its parent container.

Comment: Thanks, problem is that doesn't work for earlier browsers, also the width of the centred element must be fixed. Those aren't an issue with the `align` attribute approach. I'm after *exact* functionality. :)